# Visual Studio 2010 - Productivity Power Tools - Highlight Current Line's colour resets on VS reload

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010 Pro installed with ***"Productivity Power Tools"*** being the **only** extention and ***"Highlight Current Line"*** the only option enbled on that extention.

I then change the colour of the *"Current Line (Extention)"* to a darker colour (as my background is black not white and the light grey is to harsh)

**BUT** every time I open/restart Visual Stuio 2010 the current line is highlighted with the default light grey colour again. I can correct this by opening up "Tools", "Options...", "Enviroment", "Fonts and Colors" and clicking "OK" but I need to do this ***EVERY TIME*** I load VS2010.

Does anyone know a work around or solution to this?

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT:
Just to be clear the settings are **NOT** lost they are just not applied after I start VS2010 until I enter the "Fonts and Colors" option section and just click OK.

I don't even need to change or reapply the settings as they are already there! I suspect a fault in the power tools extension but from what I have read on the site MS aren't updating them now as they are working on the next version of VS.

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of Visual Studio open?

Comment: I often do have more than one instance open but I have tried closing all of them reopening one (which had reset the settings again), opening the font & colour options (to correct the colours again), closing it, waiting a few seconds and reopening it and still the settings reset to the default colours. So I am fairly sure it isn't due to that. Thanks though. Any other ideas?

Comment: I downloaded the latest Power Tools. I'm using 2010 Ultimate with Resharper as well. I couldn't reproduce the problem - even when I had multiple instances open. Clearly my environment is a little different.

Comment: no sometimes if you have more than one instance open and close one or if you open up more instances the settings get resetet - happens to me from time to time - just exprot all your Settings like Blanthor suggested and reload if it happens.

Comment: This isn't the problem as it's not resetting the setting just not applying the ONE Colour setting "Current Line (Extension)". Also Blanthor I am NOT using Resharper (which I believe also highlights current line and likely works but costs) so if you tested with Reshaper installed it could be you where using Resharper's instead. ;)

Comment: Resharper does not highlight the entire line, at least not with the default settings. I just mentioned it, so you knew how my environment differs. There is a way to create a macro to import setttings for you - I know it's a kluge :) I'll try to find this information.

Comment: Did you change both 'Current Line' and Current Line Inactive'? I use a dark color too. The highlight is light grey when the editor window does not have the focus for me. I didn't change it to a darker color. If you click in your code does this change?

Comment: I get the same issue as you Zasurus. All of my color settings display correctly except the highlight line color from Productivity Power Tools. Then if I click Tools -> Options -> Environment and select Fonts and Colors, then click 'OK'... the color now displays correctly as I had previously configured it. Not sure why it always does that. Hopefully somebody eventually figures it out.

Comment: Blanthor: Yer I have both lines setup correctly and they DO show correctly until you close and reopen then they SHOW (not revert as the correct values are still stored) to the default for JUST the previously mentioned lines and as said before and again by Scott simply opening and closing the config is enough to fix it but EVERY time you open VS2010 :(

Comment: It appears that I can reproduce your problem now without fail. I believe this is a problem with the PowerTools, as you suggest.

Comment: Same problem here... anyone knows a solution?!

Comment: @tanathos Afraid not Blanthor has raised a bug with MS (see comment for answer below) and this is their response: "Thanks for letting us know about this issue. Unfortunately, this is an issue in Visual Studio 2010 itself (rather than in the Power Tools) so we cannot fix this in the extension. Now that the highlight current line power tool has been integrated into Visual Studio 11, we believe that this issue is now "fixed" so I'm resolving this issue as such." I have just purchased ReSharper which works well and I would recommend it.

Comment: I've been using Productivity Power Tools for years and have also had this problem. I'll try disabling it for a while and seeing what happens. Thanks for the suggestion, Blanthor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no real reason this is happening to you. I suggest you get the latest updates of Visual Studio 2010 and Power Tools if you haven't already.

As a work around you might save your settings through the **Tools|Import and Export Settings** menu. Export only **Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors**

Comment: Thanks but no good. I already have the newest versions of both and as I said I don't need to reload the settings as they are NOT lost they just aren't applied to the "Current Line (Extension)" (only the rest of the colours I have changed are applied fine) until I open the "Fonts and Colors" settings and click OK. :(

Comment: As there still apears to be no other option this must be the best! ;) I have marked it as the answer. Thanks for you help Blanthor.

Comment: I've reported the bug here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/710197/font-resets-for-productivity-power-tools. I stole some of your descriptions. I hope you don't mind my American spellings :)

Comment: Thanks for that and I don't mind d spelling at all! I find our spelling very annoying... BUT if I correct for my net work I will forget when I go to work! ;) We (British spelling) seem to have just added random letters all over the place! ;) Pity Noah Webster didn't push for the changes to phonetic for the British as well! ;)

Comment: any solution for this issue? i am having the same problem with my visual studio now. some of the setting in Font/Color doesn't stay over visual studio restart.

Comment: @Eatdoku: If you go to the bug report mentioned in the above comments, you'll read that Microsoft's "fix" is to use Visual Studio 2011. There is no real solution avaialable for 2010 users.

Answer (score -1):

Disable the powertools option for current line highlight and enable the Resharper current line highlight.

Works like a charm

Comment: Yes I'm sure it would IF I had Resharper! :p

Comment: Apparently not very well! Constantly trying to work around problems like this. ;)